# How to get details based on case sensitives in node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am writing a login call in node js for login and i followed the below way,

```
    exports.signin = function (req, res) {
    var student = new Student(req.body);
    student.status = '1';
    var data = {},
    item = {
         'username' : student.username ,
         'password' : student.password 
    };console.log(item)
    Student.find(item,function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
            return err;
        } if(result != []){console.log(result)
            data = { status: true, error_code: 0,result:result, message: 'Login successfull' };
        }else{
            data = { status: false, error_code: 1, message: 'Usernme or password is wrong' };

        }
 res.json(data);
    });
}
```

Here i am comparing username and password.For an example,my username and passwords are like

```
    username: Arnold
    password: Arnold123
```

unfortunate thing is if i give like this also it is accepting,

```
    username: ArnOld
    password: ArnoLd123
```

But when i am testing ,it was getting logged in with small 'a' also,so can any one suggest me how can i compare my login details with case if case exists.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For Email/Username save data either as UPPERCASE or LOWERCASE in DB and find accordingly. Also, make sure that you have set a unique index flag on Email/Username

For password, don't save then as string as this will result in security leak. make a hash of the password and then store them in DB.

As you are using node.js you can use [Bcrypt Module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt). It has an inbuilt method for hashing passwords and then to compare them also.